# How to write a recursive function for finding the height of a binary search tree?

Tags: binary-search-tree

Here is the class I'm using

from tree_node import TreeNode

class BinarySearchTree:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.size = 0

def length(self):
    return self.size

def __len__(self):
    return self.size

def __iter__(self):
    return self.root.__iter__()

def __str__(self):
    """Returns a string representation of the tree
       rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise"""

    def strHelper(root, level):
        resultStr = ""
        if root:
            resultStr += strHelper(root.rightChild, level+1)
            resultStr += "| " * level
            resultStr += str(root.key) + "\n"
            resultStr += strHelper(root.leftChild, level+1)                
        return resultStr


    return strHelper(self.root, 0)


def __contains__(self,key):
    if self._get(key,self.root):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get(self,key):
    if self.root:
        res = self._get(key,self.root)
        if res:
            return res.payload
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None

def _get(self,key,currentNode):
    if not currentNode:
        return None
    elif currentNode.key == key:
        return currentNode
    elif key < currentNode.key:
        return self._get(key,currentNode.leftChild)
    else:
        return self._get(key,currentNode.rightChild)

def __getitem__(self,key):
    return self.get(key) 

def __setitem__(self,k,v):
    self.put(k,v)

def put(self,key,val):
    if self.root:
        self._put(key,val,self.root)
    else:
        self.root = TreeNode(key,val)
    self.size = self.size + 1

def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
    if key < currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                      parent=currentNode)
    elif key > currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
        else:
            currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                      parent=currentNode)
    else:
        currentNode.payload = val
        self.size -= 1

def delete(self,key):
  if self.size > 1:
      nodeToRemove = self._get(key,self.root)
      if nodeToRemove:
          self.remove(nodeToRemove)
          self.size = self.size-1
      else:
          raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')
  elif self.size == 1 and self.root.key == key:
      self.root = None
      self.size = self.size - 1
  else:
      raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')

def __delitem__(self,key):
    self.delete(key)


def remove(self,currentNode):
  if currentNode.isLeaf(): #leaf
    if currentNode == currentNode.parent.leftChild:
        currentNode.parent.leftChild = None
    else:
        currentNode.parent.rightChild = None
  elif currentNode.hasBothChildren(): #interior
    succ = currentNode.findSuccessor()
    succ.spliceOut()
    currentNode.key = succ.key
    currentNode.payload = succ.payload

  else: # this node has one child
    if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
      if currentNode.isLeftChild():
          currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
          currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
      elif currentNode.isRightChild():
          currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
          currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild
      else:
          currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.leftChild.key,
                             currentNode.leftChild.payload,
                             currentNode.leftChild.leftChild,
                             currentNode.leftChild.rightChild)

    else:
      if currentNode.isLeftChild():
          currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
          currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.rightChild
      elif currentNode.isRightChild():
          currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
          currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
      else:
          currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.rightChild.key,
                             currentNode.rightChild.payload,
                             currentNode.rightChild.leftChild,
                             currentNode.rightChild.rightChild)



def height(self):

    def heightHelper(subtreeRoot):
        """ Recursive helper method to determine the height of the BST. """
        if subtreeRoot.leftChild:
            heightHelper(subtreeRoot.leftChild)
        elif subtreeRoot:
            heightHelper(subtreeRoot.rightChild)
        return 1 + max(height(subtreeroot.leftChild), height(subtreeRoot.rightChild))

    return heightHelper(self.root)
```

I need to modify the heightHelper function in order to get the height of the tree. I know how to recursively through the tree but I'm wondering how I keep track of the height while I'm doing that. The max return statement isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper function doesn't uses the values of the recursive calls and calls the `height` function:

```
def height(self):
    def heightHelper(inTree):
        if inTree:
            theLeftHeight = 1 + heightHelper(inTree.leftChild)
            theRightHeight = 1 + heightHelper(inTree.rightChild)
            return max(theLeftHeight, theRightHeight)
        else:
            return 0
    return heightHelper(self.root)
```